# Chromatic 8 graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am looking for chromatic number 8 graphs that use the least number of edges preferably. Also my graph shouldn't be k8.

I don't want the Mycielski graph.

suggest any online database or resources if they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the [Database of Interesting Graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/search) on [The House of Graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org).

Here you can search, for example, for a graph with chromatic number equal to $8$, but clique number less than $8$ (so that the graph does not contain a $K_8$). This gives three results [[1]](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/33954) [[2]](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/34470) [[3]](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/1196), none of which come from the Mycielski construction.